# Have screensaver with photos in Windows 7 Pro on primary screen or on several screens

Tags: windows-7, display, screensaver

The screensaver with photos on Windows 7 Pro doesnt display the photo on the primary/default screen but on the leftmost extended one.

How do you get on on the primary screen and on all 3 screens?

Comment: Are you asking about the screensaver or the wallpaper?

Comment: The screensaver.